# Minesweep Game (Setting Bomb & Claiming Winner) - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie at JavaScript and wanting to learn more about it. I am trying to create my own MineSweeping Game but I am having trouble setting one of my tiles as a trap and declaring the winner when the player presses all the tiles and avoids the trap. I was wondering if anyone could help me? I know if the player were to click on the trap, I would use a break; function at the end to end the game and display "Game Over" but I'm not sure exactly how to set the tile function to be called? And if the player clicks on 3/4 correct tiles, it would say "You won!" Would my function contain something like
`if (clicked_tile != trap) { document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "You won!"?`
Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
#t1, #t2, #t3, #t4{
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}
#t1{background-color: red;}
#t2{background-color: blue;}
#t3{background-color: green;}
#t4{background-color: yellow;}
</style>
<script>

  var trap = Math.floor(Math.random()*4+1);
  function play_game(id)
  {
    var tile_id = "t" + id;
    var clicked_tile = document.getElementById(tile_id);
    if (clicked_tile.style.backgroundColor == "grey"){
      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML =
      "This was already clicked";
    }
    else
    {
              clicked_tile.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
              document.getElementById("info").innerHTML =
              "The trap is " + trap;
    }
  }
     </script>
   </head>

  <body>
   <div class = "container">
      <div id="t1" onclick="play_game('1')"></div>
      <div id="t2" onclick="play_game('2')"></div>
      <div id="t3" onclick="play_game('3')"></div>
      <div id="t4" onclick="play_game('4')"></div>
   </div>
  <div id="info"></div>

 </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: It looks like a lot of pieces are missing. I don't see where you set which tile is the trap or check if the trap was clicked, for example. The answer to your general question is that when you check if the clicked tile is a trap you also check if the number of clicked tiles === the number of safe tiles. If true, you know they won.

P.S.
Take out the inline JavaScript and use event handlers instead of `onclick`

Comment: minor formating

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. For the losing condition (clicking the trap), you could consider adding another `if` statement:

```
else if (id == trap){ ... you lose! ... }
```

The winning condition is a bit tougher. You might consider a structure using JavaScript objects:

```
//create a default minefield
var mineboard = {
    'tile1': {
        'safe': true,
        'clicked': false
    },
    'tile2': {
        'safe': true,
        'clicked': false
    },
    'tile3': {
        'safe': true,
        'clicked': false
    },
    'tile4': {
        'safe': true,
        'clicked': false
    }
};

//set the trap
var trap = Math.floor(Math.random()*4+1); //will be something like 'tile2'
mineboard['tile' + trap].safe = false; //now a tile is not safe!
```

You could use an object like this to keep track of the state of your application. As the user clicks tiles, set `clicked` to `true`. Each time the user clicks, check all your tiles--if you count three places where `safe` is `true` and `clicked` is `true`, you know your user has won.